# AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'eval'

Tags: python-2.7, object, attributes, eval, sympy

In the following code, which calculates the eigenstates for the quantum harmonic oscillator, and the product of mr and gaussq is equal to the ground state, I'm trying to get the the eigenstates, and make a plot which contains all the subplots for each.

However, running the code returns:

```
*for i in xx: rePsi.eval(i)
AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'eval'*
```

**Code Example:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import sympy as sym
from math import *

w=1
m=1
hbar=1
x = sym.symbols ('x')
a=-1
b=1
phi_n=0
psi=0
plt.ylim(-1,1 )
plt.xlim(-3,3)

print('give me the number of states')
nn = int(input())
if (nn<0):
    print 'must be >=0\n'
if (nn>=0):
    print('time to evaluate')
    t = float(input())
    if (t<0):
        print 'Time must be >=0'

print '   '

mr = float((m*w/(hbar*pi))**0.25)
gaussq = sym.exp(-m*w*x**2/(2*hbar))

fig = [0 for i in range(nn)]
fig1 = plt.figure(1)

xx = np.arange(-3., 3.,0.1)
for n in range (0,nn,2):
    H_root = sym.sqrt(1/(2**n*float(sym.factorial(n))))
    Hermite = (-1)**n*sym.exp(m*w*x**2/hbar)*sym.diff(sym.exp(-m*w*x**2/hbar),x,n)
    Energy = hbar*w*(n+0.5)
    phi_n = sym.simplify(H_root*mr*gaussq*Hermite)
    arg_int = sym.simplify(phi_n*gaussq*mr)
    c_n = sym.simplify(sym.integrate(arg_int, (x,a,b)))
    psi_n = c_n*phi_n*sym.exp(-1j*w*t*(n+0.5))
    psi_n_re = sym.re(psi_n)
    psi_n_im = sym.im(psi_n)
    psi += sym.simplify(psi_n)
    rePsi = sym.re(psi) 
    imPsi = sym.im(psi)
    print type (rePsi)
    print type (imPsi)
    for i in xx: rePsi.eval(i)
    for i in xx: imPsi.eval(i)
    list_rePsi= rePsi
    list_imPsi= imPsi
    plt.subplot(nn, 1, (n+2)/2)
    plt.plot(xx,list_repsi)
    plt.plot(xx,list_impsi)

plt.show()
print '\n'+str(psi)
```

Comment: So, an object does not have an attribute `eval`. What made you think it should have it.

Comment: perhaps you're thinking of `evalf`?

Comment: I'm not an expert, because of that I'm looking for help, and yes, I,ve already tried with evalf, but it didn't work

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you intended to create a list where you replace the symbol x with the values in xx? You could try `list_rePsi = [rePsi.subs(x, i) for i in xx]` but Python is case sensitive so make sure you plot `list_rePsi` not `list_repsi`.